# It is common to ask a caller to communicate via a queue?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, design-patterns, architecture, message-queue

Originally the team was thinking of developing a C# service for a parent company. The service would receive requests and then the service would ping a 3rd party and return the result.

Instead of it being synchronous, we decided we would have an AWS SQS and SNS queue for both requests and results. Our company would give credentials to our AWS for the parent to write and notify from a request queue.

Then this service wouldn't be a service, it would be a processor. It would then read from the queue and sent the requests and writeback the results to another SQS, SNS that would notify an API on the parent company side.

Question: Is this a good design? We are bypassing the use of services to prevent having to have retry logic and having to develop clients, rather we just communicate via queues.

Comment: I think your question should be more: is the type of work suited to it? Does the caller need immediate feedback? If the caller needs feedback, how does it get it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many advantages to such an approach.

- You allow your client and "processor" to focus on their
  responsibilities and interact via a message bus
- You allow the client and processor to be independent and decoupled of
  each other, especially in terms of technology and programming
  language used.
- The can both be scaled independently as and when required.
- If one of them is "down" then the messages can still be accumulated
  on the message bus and won't get lost (assuming you have a suitable
  TTL to cover this)
- If the services offered grows, you can introduce new queues to
  process them without impact the current client and processor
- They are asynchronous
- You can have multiple producers and/or consumers
- Etc

There are of course disadvantages

- Latency is increased.  For some situations this is a issue
- You are dependent upon a 3rd party product
- If using AWS, Azure, etc, you are dependent upon a 3rd party company
- Additional costs from 3pp party & product
- Debugging can be more difficult
- Tracing can be more difficult
- Security can be more difficult
- If a client or receiver goes down, it might not be immediately
  obvious.  Leading to a build up of messages, each of which might have
  a limited time to live! (what happens if this occurs at the weekend?)
- Acknowledging receipt of requests is difficult
- Ensuring messages don't get lost when a process fails is more
  difficult
- Etc

You can of course find more about these on the internet.

So there is nothing wrong with this as an approach.  The only question really is

> "is this the right architecture for our use case(s)?"

Only you can determine this by weighing up the pros and cons, maybe together with your customer.